# How to retrieve an xml nodes root / top level parent

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

Hi how do i retrieve the top level parent of an xml node in actionscript please?

```
    <companies>
        <company id="1" name="boo" level="1">
            <company id="2" name="hoo" level="2">
                <company id="3" name="ooo" level="3"/>
            </company>
        </company>
    </companies>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit (final):

I think I get what you are asking:  what is the `company.(@level = 1)` node that has the selected `company.(@level = 3)` as a child.  This is also known as an "ancestor" of the selected node.  AS3 XML does not have a robust ancestor syntax, so you have to step upwards manually.

For unknown levels of parenting, use a loop like the comments in [this post discuss](http://www.ultrashock.com/forum/viewthread/124113/).  Note that the following code uses the `id` attribute for searching.  This is because all `id`s must be unique within a single XML, so you are guaranteed to find the id.

```
var xml:XML = <companies>
        <company id="1" name="boo" level="1">
            <company id="2" name="hoo" level="2">
                <company id="3" name="ooo" level="3"/>
            </company>
        </company>
        <company id="4" name="boo" level="1">
            <company id="5" name="hoo" level="2">
                <company id="6" name="ooo" level="3"/>
            </company>
        </company>
        <company id="7" name="boo" level="1">
            <company id="8" name="hoo" level="2">
                <company id="9" name="ooo" level="3"/>
            </company>
        </company>
    </companies>

// just for testing:
var selectedNodeXML:XML = 
    <company id="8" name="hoo" level="2" />

var selectedID:String = selectedNodeXML.@id;
trace("selectedID = " + selectedID);

var ancestorID:String = "";

for each( var companyNode:XML in xml.elements("*") )
{
    trace( "searching: " + companyNode.toXMLString() );  
    trace( "res: " + (companyNode..company.(@id == selectedID).@id == selectedID));
    if(
       companyNode.@id == selectedNodeXML.@id
       //|| companyNode.contains(selectedNodeXML) // You can use this if nothing gets messed up . . .
       || companyNode..company.(@id == selectedID).@id == selectedID // . . . but I think this is more reliable.
    ){
        ancestorID = companyNode.@id.toString();
        break;
    }
}

trace( "significant ancestor ID: " + ancestorID );
```

Comment: thought of that one however my problem is getting the top level parent of a selected node for example if i have selected <company id="3" name="ooo" level="3"/> how do i get its top level parent

Comment: What do you mean selected?  And the top level parent is always the root, so I am not sure what you are trying to find.  Give an example as best you can of what you have in your selection, and what the parent might be.

Comment: thanks for your reply What i am doing is working with a tree control in flex and i have a function which works with the selected xml node, but my function needs to know what the id is of the top level (level 1) parent node. I hope that is a bit clearer???

Comment: problem here is node.parent() returns the direct parent not the top level parent in other words if i have selected <company id="3" name="ooo" level="3"/> node.parent() would return <company id="2" name="hoo" level="2">, but in this case i actually need the <company id="1" name="boo" level="1">
, any ideas please ??

Comment: yeah problem here is there is no fixed depth to the tree there could be 10 to 15 levels of data within the heirarchy